# Text inside a div refusing to wrap around an image

Tags: css, html, text

I've put a solid hour into this, can't get anywhere.

Working on responsive site.

Within a Div, I have these two articles with text on the left and an image on the right side, I can't get the text to wrap around the image, I've tried setting heights on the image, floating, margins, text-align, random other attempts.

IDK WHY but CODE is impossible, i have to manually indent each line!? it jsut dosen't work for me.
Attaching jsfiddle .... http://jsfiddle.net/A8QkE/

Please help (:

Thanks.

```
.wrap {
width: 66.66666666666667%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top: 200px;  
color: #fff;

}

.nodiv p {
float: left;
/*    text-align: left;*/
display:inline;
/*    word-wrap:break-word;*/
 }
.nodiv img {
 float: right;   
 /*display: inline;    */
    /*height: 300px;*/
      /*    margin:0;*/
 }
```

http://i.imgur.com/QpN7fiu.png

Comment: I deleted some css properties that were redundant and got something like that : http://jsfiddle.net/RwkDK/

Comment: I'm trying to see what you did, I can't seem to replicate it by looking at what you sent me. Would you mind telling me what you had done? Or leaving a comment in the code? 

I'd appreciate that thanks (:

Comment: My final answer just below ;-)

Answer (score 0):

if you want the text wrap the image you cant use floats.

```
.nodiv p {
   float: left;
   /*    text-align: left;*/
   display:inline;
   /*    word-wrap:break-word;*/
 }
 .nodiv img {
 float: right;   
 /*display: inline;    */
  /*height: 300px;*/
  /*    margin:0;*/
 }
```

see the code http://jsfiddle.net/A8QkE/2/

Answer (score 0):

I just modified this css property that was avoiding you paragraph to occupy the entire space :

```
article p {
   width: 49.91666666666667%; /* DELETE THIS LINE */
  /* 460/960    */
  text-indent:4.34782608695652em;
  padding: 10px 5px 2px 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: I'm using the original code I posted.

Okay, I did that, the images only rose above the text now,

I made sure article p and article img both have float tags and neither have widths. The images are still floating above..

Comment: I posted an image in the original post so you can see what I mean with the actual images.

Thank you so much for helping btw.

Comment: But in your original JSFiddle, your text was floating on the left correctly. It was just that it didn't wrap below the image, was it? In your original Fiddle, I just delete the line I told you to get this : http://jsfiddle.net/hhf8d/ But the screenshot you just post doesn't represent your original Fiddle, does it? :/